# Configure a dynamic height for UICollectionView within UIStackView that is nested within a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uistackview

I have a `UITableView` with different cells, within one of these cells is a `UIStackView` which contains multiple UIView's, the last one being a custom class that subclasses `UICollectionView`.

So the issue I'm having is that the collectionview within the stackview doesn't appear because the height is zero. To try and get around this issue, within the custom `UICollectionView` I've tried to apply a height within using the following piece of code.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if !hasBeenLayedOut {
        hasBeenLayedOut = true
        self.apply(height: self.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height, width: nil)
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

The only problem is because after the views in the stack views have constraints applied once I apply a height constraint, the stack view items shrink to adjust their content to the collection view.

My questions is it possible to figure out the height of the collectionview before `layoutSubviews()`? I've tried to use the collectionviewContentSize but it's always 0 which is why my collectionview doesn't have a height.